# Replace Variable Inside @content Directive in SASS Mixin

Tags: sass

I'm trying to figure out a DRY and readable way to loop through color classes for each of my design patterns. A nice way I thought I could do this is to pass the CSS properties that need to be changed for each pattern to a mixin along with a variable, and the mixin would swap out the variable inside the `@content` declaration:

```
$color-list: (
    "c1" : #ed0ead, 
    "c2" : #12bc21,
    "c3" : #2666cc
);

@mixin color-variants {
    @each $class, $color in $color-list {
        &.#{$class} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

.my-module {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-size: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    @include color-variants {
        border-top-color: $color;
    }
}

.another-module {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-size: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    @include color-variants {
        background-color: rgba($color, 0.5);
        &:hover {
          color: $color;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately SASS doesn't parse the `@content` declaration along with the mixin variables, so I get a `Undefined variable: "$color"` error.

Is it possible to do something like this with existing SASS tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can use `!global` flag creating a global variable that you can read also out of mixin scope.

```
$color-list: (
    "c1" : #ed0ead, 
    "c2" : #12bc21,
    "c3" : #2666cc
);

@mixin color-variants {
    @each $class, $color in $color-list {
        $myColor: $color !global;
        &.#{$class} {
            @content;
        }
    }
}

.my-module {
    padding: 1rem;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-top-size: 5px;
    border-top-style: solid;
    @include color-variants {
        border-top-color: $myColor;
    }
}

.another-module {
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-size: 2px;
    border-style: solid;
    @include color-variants {
        background-color: rgba($myColor, 0.5);
        &:hover {
          color: $myColor;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a sassmeister for you: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8f90133f3ee1d2e67e21f086711cee39

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!

Comment: There is also https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin#passing-arguments-to-content-blocks